# Notice: unintialized string offset

Tags: php, notice

I have the following code below, which workes quite allright - but now when I have all errors reported on - I get to see this:

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 9 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\dev\lib\player.class.php on line 110 Notice:
>   Uninitialized string offset: 10 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\dev\lib\player.class.php on line 110 Notice:
>   Uninitialized string offset: 11 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\dev\lib\player.class.php on line 110 Notice:
>   Uninitialized string offset: 12 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\dev\lib\player.class.php on line 110 Notice:
>   Uninitialized string offset: 13 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\dev\lib\player.class.php on line 110

Line 110 is

```
$this->formattedname .= "<span style='color:" . $colour . "'>" . $this->username[$i] . "</span>";
```

in the foreach

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? I can't get a solution to fix these errors.. :(

```
if ($this->admin == 1) {
            $colours = explode("~", $this->gradientcolours);
            $gradient = new ColourGradient(array(0 => $colours['0'], (strlen($this->username) - 1) => $colours['1']));
            $this->formattedname .= ($this->admin == 1) ? "<b><i><a style='text-decoration: none;' title='" . $this->title . "' href='/profile/" . $this->id . "'>" : "<b><a title='" . $this->title . "' href='/profile/" . $this->id . "'>";
            $this->formattedname2 = ($this->admin == 1) ? "<b><i><a style='text-decoration: none;' title='" . $this->title . "' href='/profile/" . $this->id . "'>" : "<b><a title='" . $this->title . "' href='/profile/" . $this->id . "'>";



                    foreach($gradient as $i => $colour) {
                $this->formattedname .= "<span style='color:" . $colour . "'>" . $this->username[$i] . "</span>";

            }

            $this->formattedname .= ($this->admin == 1) ? "</a></i></b>" : "</a></b>";

            $this->formattedname2 .= ($this->admin == 1) ? "</a></i></b>" : "</a></b>";

        }
```

Comment: The username has less characters than the gradient has steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error would occur if any of the following variables were actually strings or null instead of arrays.

Try to test and initialize your arrays before you use them

```
if( !isset($this->username[$i]) ) $this->username[$i] = '' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error, but a notice. An error or a warning imply you did something wrong/made an mistake. A notice is just a hint that something might be done better.

What is is telling you, is that you are using a key which doesnt exist:

```
$array[0] = 0;
$array[1] = 1;
$array[2] = 2;

echo $array[0]; // no notice, it exists
echo $array[2]; // no notice, it exists
echo $array[9]; // the notice will fire, because key 9 doesn't exist
```

In your code I cant tell which line is 110, but im guessing `$this->username[$i]` is the problem, user 9 to 13 dont exist

If `$this->username` is not an array but a string, it will give back the Nth character:

```
$string = "example";
echo $string[1]; // will return X, an array starts counting at 0 (zero-index-based)
echo $string[50]; // blank echo, and the notice because character 50 doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use concatenation `.=` for a string, Your string must be initialized like this

```
$this->formattedname = "";
```

and after concatenate

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line:

```
$this->username[$i].
```

Your username may have say 5 characters, while $i can be say 12. Use proper conditions to validate.